# Can I do anything about an uneven six-pack?

Tags: muscle

I have an uneven six-pack and have been pushing it hard, hoping it will grow evenly. I've been training for 8 months, and there isn't any difference yet. My abs are still uneven. A trainer told me that is genetic, but I really hope there is some way to save it, as looking at my uneven abs is making me feel upset. All the sizes of my abs are different, with some big and some small.

Comment: just out of curiosity, how can six packs be uneven? What does that mean really?

Comment: some of my packs look bigger which cause some of my pack to look very small. got few of my pack is like a little to upwards making those at the top look too small. got 1 pack become so small that not alot of ppl notice it.

Comment: I've been thinking about this myself, and my best idea is to look into some of Paul Chek's stuff. He's got a rather interesting video that goes into detail about the abs, and it'd be worth looking into whether the unevenness is due to postural imbalance throughout the body.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general consensus is that its genetic. Don't be worried though - a lot of fitness models have uneven 6 packs and they still look great because they are shredded.

Comment: thanks. i am still on my way to become shredded. Is it a must to take protein shake? As i have not started drinking protein. Able to see a huge different on my body since i started training. but for the past few month it stop growing.

Comment: If you want to gain (or at least keep) your muscle while loosing fat, I would recommend dropping the weight and doing higher reps (up to 20). Pick a weight where you should be close to if not at complete failure by the 20th rep. High reps on leg exercises such as squats and leg press are especially a great way to burn fat. The other tip I'd give you is to get your food right! Estimate your body fat % (or get it checked) and then prescribe yourself a diet that feeds yourself about 130% of your minimum required calories. Under eating is as bad as over eating for a good physique.

Comment: Protein shakes are optional - I just try to get at least 40% of your calories from protein (meats mainly). Protein shakes help reach this quota.

Comment: Thanks. my body fats is at 7% now but i find myself not shredded enough. Maybe i will try dropping my weight and doing more rep.

Answer (score -3):

Well actually I just made the discovery of why abs are uneven right now, although quite grotesque, i think every man will agree with me why it is true. Put your hand next to your crotch and move it up and down, now feel your top ab on that side of whichever hand your using, your ab is actually getting used when you do this. Now relate the motion your doing to whatever you do in real life, and it is obvious why your abs arent even, its not genetics, its the fact that youve been using the same hand to pleasure yourself everynight. :)

Comment: Please link the research that has indicated this